# How to tell gradlew to export lint results file to projectDir?

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I'm building an Android application using Jenkins pipeline and Gradle.

I'd like to run Lint tests on the code and so the command which is used for that matter is:

```
./gradlew lintStagingDebug
```

For some reason this Gradle task is not creating the report.

I know that if I'd run lint like so:

```
lint <project_dir> --xml xml_dest_path
```

It would create the report.

But since through out the whole pipeline I'm using gradlew to run the relevant tasks (clean, lint, compile, unittest, assemble) I'd like to use gradlew for this task as well but I'm not sure how to tell Gradle to export the lint report.

Another thing I've tried is to edit the `project/build.gradle` file and change this section:

```
lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
```

to (according to [Lint official documentation](http://apdr.qiniudn.com/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html))

```
lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        xmlOutput projectDir/lint-results.xml
    }
```

But then I get an error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':App01'.
> No signature of method: java.io.File.div() is applicable for argument types: (com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint_Decorated) values: [task ':App01:lint']
```

Anyone knows how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it.

```
stage('Lint run') {
    sh """
        export HOME=$GRADLE_USER_HOME
        export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
        OUTPUTFILE="lint-results.txt"
        touch \$OUTPUTFILE
        ./gradlew lint${BUILDFLAV}${BUILDTYPE} -x lint 2>&1 | tee \$OUTPUTFILE
        """
})
```

**Explanation:**

In order to keep using gradlew to run lint test on the code, I've defined an output file and added at the end of the gradlew command redirection of stdOut and stdErr to this output file using the Linux command "tee".

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the XML report output file in Gradle in the following way:

```
lintOptions {
    xmlOutput file("lint-results.xml")
}
```

The xmlOutput method requires a file type argument. I have used the relative path in the argument. You can also use it with projectDir.

```
lintOptions {
    xmlOutput file("$projectDir/lint-results.xml")
}
```